# Create Android OAUTH client fails with: "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (4800001)"

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-oauth, google-play-games

So I am trying to setup Google Play Games Services in the Google Play Developer Console.

This worked for me yesterday.

Today however, when setting up another app, and trying to link an android app to the games services, I get this error:

```
An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (4800001)
```

I got this in:
Google Play Developer Console -> Games Services -> [game] -> Linked Apps -> STEP 2 Authorize your app.

This happens regardless which key I try, my release key, or my debug key.

I don't understand why this would be happening, as it was working yesterday, albeit for an app without real-time multi player. The app I am trying to setup now needs real-time multiplayer, but I'm not sure whether this difference is the cause of it. Maybe servers at google are down?

I get the error each time I try, regardless which browser I use, or which OS. I tried on Ubuntu Firefox and OSX Safari.

Comment: I'm having same problem now. Maybe their server's not working properly ATM?

Comment: Good to know that I am not the only one. If it is infrastructure problems, then I think Google in unaware, because it has not been listed at https://status.cloud.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a temporary breakage in the Google Play Developer Console.

They fixed it today, by rolling back changes to the console, see:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/153#issuecomment-134749998

Answer (score 0):

I opened https://console.developers.google.com/ page and successfully registered my app there while I was having same issue as you.

Comment: I found the 'add credentials' in the developers console, but this video specifically warns against using that console to create clientids, as it will not make the known to game services: https://developers.google.com/live/shows/5936979195723776